# How can I add a column in the wp_list_table of the admin area?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, admin, wp-list-table

[image]

So my question is pretty much what you see in the picture. In my custom post type of "Products" how can I add an extra column like SEO Yoast did to my main table which is called **WP_List_Table**. I have the code figured out as to how I will get an out of stock feature to show up depending on if the item has a custom_field of "Out of Stock" set to true or false. Thats not problem but how can I target that area of the table in my code. I would assume that it would be a filter, not to sure on how that would work but id really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: You will find many tutorials to do this : http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need is the set of filters and actions to add custom columns to post edit screens:

- [manage_edit-post_type_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns): used to add columns
- [manage_posts_custom_column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column): used to print the content of each row of the column
- manage_edit-post_type_sortable_columns: used to register sortable columns. Undocumented.
- [request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request): you may need to use this filter in combination with `manage_edit-post_type_sortable_columns`.

For example, I use this code to add a sortable column with post hits information from a custom meta field:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns',  'add_new_columns' );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns' );
add_filter( 'request', 'hits_column_orderby' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns' );
/**
* Add new columns to the post table
*
* @param Array $columns - Current columns on the list post
*/
function add_new_columns($columns){

    $column_meta = array( 'hits' => 'Hits' );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 6, true ) + $column_meta + array_slice( $columns, 6, NULL, true );
    return $columns;

}

// Register the columns as sortable
function register_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['hits'] = 'hits';
    return $columns;
}

//Add filter to the request to make the hits sorting process numeric, not string
function hits_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'hits' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'hits',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }

    return $vars;
}

/**
* Display data in new columns
*
* @param  $column Current column
*
* @return Data for the column
*/
function custom_columns($column) {

    global $post;

    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'hits':
            $hits = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hits', true );
            echo (int)$hits;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great! How would you make the additional key you add to the array which is the extra column first to the left. Like when you see the wp_list_table the fist is title. How can I make my custom column first?

Comment: In `function add_new_columns($columns)`, the var `$columns` is an array and you can insert the new column in the position you want using normal PHP code for that. I use `array_slice` to insert my custom column in the 6th position but you could use any other PHP array manipulation thecnique. For example [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to prepend a element to the beginning of an array. But this is a pure PHP question that may be more suitable for StackOverflow than WPSE.

Comment: Ok got it, the part that was giving me trouble was what function I had to manipulate to array in.